# How to filter xPath after an element with an ID

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm currently having an issue with using of xPath : I can get the element I want with a standard xPath expression like :

`/html/body/form/div[13]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]`

But the problem is that those div[] number are always moving on this webpage, so I need to filter more, and I got a table with an ID that contains what I need, I need to get the td's in this table. So my xPath expression would be like :

`//table[@id='myTableID']/tr[3]/td[4]`

And then, while my first expression returns me the content I need, the second doesn't. Is it possible to filter after an ID on xPath ? And if not, how can I do it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you used single slash `/` instead of double slash `//`.

```
/html/body/form/div[13]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]
```

The structure is as follows

```
table -> body -> tr -> td
```

```
//table[@id='myTableID']/tr[3]/td[4]
```

If you use single slash `/` it looks for direct child of `table` element. That's why you can't find the element because `tr` is not a child of `table`. It's child of `tbody` element. There are 2 ways you can do:
Include `tbody` in the xpath:

```
//table[@id='myTableID']/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]
```

Or use double slash `//` to find for any element under `table` element. Child, grandchild and so on...

Try below xpath:

```
//table[@id='myTableID']//tr[3]/td[4]
```

Comment: Ok, it's perfectly working ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: @ValentindeMandatdeGrancey Please accept my answer. See [how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I will be able to do it in 4 minutes, It will be done !